# no-duplicate-selectors error for different selectors inside the same file

Tags: stylelint, astroturf, css-in-js

I am using stylelint within a CSS-IN-JS project (here using astroturf, but I face the same pattern using any CSS-IN-JS library such as styled-components as well).

I define different styled elements within the same file, and therefore sometimes end up having duplicated selectors and/or import rules.

```
/* style.js */
import styled from 'astroturf';

export const StyledComponentA = styled('div')`
  transform: scale(0);

  &.visible {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
`;

export const StyledComponentB = styled('div')`
  opacity: 0;

  /* -> stylelint error: Unexpected duplicate selector "&.visible" */
  &.visible {
    opacity: 1;
  }
`;
```

Which I compose this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyledComponentA, StyledComponentB } from './style';

export const Component = ({ isVisible }) => (
  <StyledComponentA visible={isVisible}>
    <StyledComponentB visible={isVisible}>Whatever</StyledComponentB>
  </StyledComponentA>
);
```

Is there a way to set these stylelint rules on blocks instead of an entire file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to set these stylelint rules on blocks instead of an entire file?

There is not.

Rules like `no-duplicate-selectors` are scoped to *a source* and stylelint treats the following as sources:

- entire files
- code passed to the `code` option of the [node API](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/cli.md)
- `stdin` passed to the [CLI](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/node-api.md)

When writing CSS-in-JS, it might be advisable to turn off the rules scoped to sources. You can turn them off:

- entirely in your [configuration object](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md#rules) e.g. `"no-duplicate-selectors": null`
- on a case-by-case basis using [command comments](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md#turning-rules-off-from-within-your-css)

Comment: That's sad really, I like the rules themselves